# Hibernate @Where annotation will not apply to collection count query when EXTRA Lazy

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hibernate-mapping

I got OneToMany mapping

```
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA)
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
@Where(clause = "is_del = 0")
private List<MyEntity> activities = Lists.newArrayList();
```

Access to this field will send bellow SQLs

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        count(id) 
    from
        activity_info 
    where
        user_id =?



Hibernate: 
    select
        ...
    from
        activity_info activities0_ 
    inner join
        addr_info addrinfoen1_ 
            on activities0_.addr_info_id=addrinfoen1_.id 
    where
        (
            activities0_.is_del = 0
        ) 
        and activities0_.user_id=?
```

Due to the EXTRA lazy, access to `activities.size()` will only send the first query, the `@Where` condition has been **ignored**.

Is this a bug or am I wrong about this usage ?